# jQuery - Load path error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie in jQuery and im trying to learn how to use Load() in jQuery.
I took script from this page : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jQuery_ajax_load.asp
and then put the demo_test.txt in the same folder as my index.cshtml file.
No matter what I tried to write as path I always get "error 404 file not found".
Below my index page

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#przycisk").click(function () { 
            $("#test").load("demo_test.txt", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                if (statusTxt == "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if (statusTxt == "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });    
        }); 
    });
    </script>
    <div id="test">
    <span>Nowy Tekst</span>
    </div>

    <button id="przycisk" class="btn btn-default">press me!</button>
```

Here my files structure:
[image]

I read many similar question on stackoverflow but still can't fix it. Can anyone tell me what shouldI do?

Comment: Rule no:1 Dont use w3schools, for more info check w3fools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found answer.
Putting file in the same folder as Views etc is a bad idea because IIS is changing paths so I couldn't open file.
Simple solution. Create new folder eg. "Data" put there out file and use code like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").text("trolololo");

        $("#przycisk").click(function () {
            $("#test").load("../Data/demo_test.txt", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                if (statusTxt == "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if (statusTxt == "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnX").on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
}); 

<button id="btnX">Click me</button>
<div class="text"></div>
```

[Check this jquery datatype link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)